# How to make JWT cookie authentication in Laravel

Tags: api, authentication, cookies, laravel-5, jwt

I want to have JWT authentication in Laravel >=5.2, using [this (Tymon JWT-auth) library](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth) but I want to put JWT token into HttpOnly Cookies - to protect JWT token from steal from XSS attack.

1. I set up Tymon library and... in project:  app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider@mapWebRoutes i deactivate execution 'web' middelware group for all requests (which is default laravel behavior - you can see it by `php artisan route:list`) by remove `'middleware' => 'web'` (If I don't do it, i will see CSRF problem with post request).
2. in routes.php i write:

> ```
> Route::group(['middleware' =>'api', 'prefix' => '/api/v1', 'namespace' => 'Api\V1'], function () {
>     Route::post('/login', 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin');
>     ...
>     Route::get('/projects', 'ProjectsController@getProjects');
> }
> ```

3. In may Api\V1\Auth\AuthController@postLogin i generate token and send it back as httpOnly cookie:

   ```
   ...
   try
   {
       $user = User::where('email','=',$credentials['email'])->first();

       if ( !($user && Hash::check($credentials['password'], $user->password) ))
       {
           return response()->json(['error' => 'invalid_credentials'], 401);
       }

       $customClaims = ['sub' => $user->id, 'role'=> $user->role, 'csrf-token' => str_random(32) ];
       $payload = JWTFactory::make($customClaims);
       $token = JWTAuth::encode($payload);
   } catch(...) {...}
   return response()->json($payload->toArray())->withCookie('token', $token, config('jwt.ttl'), "/", null, false, true);
   ```
4. And, yeah here question starts. I would like to do something (may be modifiy laravel `Auth` class) on each request:

   - get coookie from request
   - decode it
   - check is right (if not trhow 401)
   - get user from DB
   - and make that method Auth::user() works every where like in usual way in laravel (so i can use it in each Controller for example)

Any ideas how to do point 4 ?

**UPDATE**

I also add here protection for CSRF attack - csrf-token is in JWT, and it is also return in body of response for login request (so JS have acces to this csrf-token) (i return only public part of JWT token in login response, whole JWT is return only in cookie, so it is XSS safe) -  then front JS must copy csrf-token into header of each request. Then the middelware JWTAuthentiacate (in my answer below) compare csrf-token header with csrf-token field in JWT payload - if they are similar then request pass csrf test.

Comment: @Atlas-Pio it was long time ago and I no't remember - for 2 years I less use Laravel and more focus on frontend (Angular) - but I think - all informations are in this question - and in my answer below - however If you have some concrete problem to set it up - create new stack overflow question and give me link here in comment - may be I can help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it simple by creating middleware.

In handle() method just get cookie from request, decode it and login a user using id with this Laravel method:

```
Auth::loginUsingId($userIdFromToken);
```

Comment: Wow - yeach - it's briliant idea! I implement It and works exactly what I want :)

Answer (score 2):

I implement @ŁukaszKuczmaja idea in this way an it works! :) . So i create file in `app/Http/Middleware/JWTAuthenticate.php` :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use JWTAuth;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Token;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenExpiredException;
use Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException;

class JWTAuthenticate
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  $guard
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        try {
            if(!$request->headers->has('csrf-token')) throw new TokenMismatchException();
            $rawToken = $request->cookie('token');
            $token = new Token($rawToken);
            $payload = JWTAuth::decode($token);
            if($payload['csrf-token'] != $request->headers->get('csrf-token')) throw new TokenMismatchException();
            Auth::loginUsingId($payload['sub']);
        } catch(\Exception $e) {
            if( $e instanceof TokenExpiredException) {
                // TODO token refresh here
            }
            return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

In `app\Http\Kernel.php@$routeMiddelware` I add line:

```
'jwt.auth'    => \App\Http\Middleware\JWTAuthenticate::class,
```

My routing file looks like this now:

```
Route::group(['middleware' =>'api', 'prefix' => '/api/v1', 'namespace' => 'Api\V1'], function () {

    Route::post('/login', 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin');

    Route::group(['middleware' =>'jwt.auth'], function () {
        Route::post('/projects', 'ProjectsController@postProjects');
        Route::get('/projects', 'ProjectsController@getProjects');
        Route::put('/projects/{project}', 'ProjectsController@putProjects');
        Route::delete('/projects/{project}', 'ProjectsController@deleteProjects');
    });

});
```

And for instance in `app/Http/Controllers/Api/V1/ProjectsController.php` i have:

```
public function getProjects() {
    $uid = Auth::user()->id;
    return Project::where('user_id','=',$uid)->get();
}
```

Comment: Kamil, hi! I use jwt-auth in approach with httponly cookie, but I'm stuck with csrf-token and api auth. How should I get the token from the server and where should I store it? Should I get it with the first request to the API? And is it good idea to store it in the localstorage? If I will send it with the cookie and store it in the browser storage, it will be send back with every request to the server and it makes no sense

Comment: Look on my QUESTION update - details are there. Alternatively you can also turn of crsf token for API like e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40910429/860099)

Answer (score -1):

Actually you can put every route that needs authentication within a route group and add the middleware like this:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['jwt.auth']], function () {
    Route::patch('/profile', 'UserController@update');
});
```

The middleware already does what you wanted so there is no need to write additional logic. Don't use an additional handle method.

Within your i.e. UserController you can then i.e.

```
$user = \Auth::user();
```

And i.e. depending what you need...

```
// assign fields
$user->save();

return 'success'; // or whatever you need
```

Don't reinvent the wheel and keep things DRY.

Comment: I guess you didn't understand the question. It's not about using jwt as it comes out of box, it's about using jwt as httpOnly cookie, not with `Bearer` auth. You can't use jwt as httpOnly cookie without any custom middleware.