# How to handle oauth2 and csrf token laravel

Tags: php, laravel, oauth, oauth-2.0, laravel-5

I installed Laravel 5.2 and [oAuth2 Server Laravel](https://github.com/lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel)
 in my project. I have to use same function for web-site and web-api. For web-site my function is working properly but when I use same function for web-api shown error `TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 67:`.

My Route

```
/* for web*/
Route::post('admin/user_login', 'Auth\AuthController@authenticate');

/* for mobile api */
Route::group(['prefix'=>'api/','before' => 'oauth'], function()
{
    Route::post('/user/login', 'Auth\AuthController@authenticate');

});
```

When I use this controller for web, this code working fine but when I call API that time shown error. How I can handle this? I have to use **oAuth** route and web route parallel. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to disable csrfToken verification for routes starting with api to do that edit your `app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php` file and add `api/*` in the $except array the sample file from laravel app repo is as below

https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/5.2/app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php

just make it something like

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken as BaseVerifier;
class VerifyCsrfToken extends BaseVerifier
{
    /**
     * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = [
        'api/*'
    ];
}
```

also you have to remove oauth middleware from authenticate route, because during authentication the token is not available so route goes something like below

```
Route::group(['prefix'=>'api/'], function()
{
    Route::post('/user/login', 'Auth\AuthController@authenticate');
    Route::group(['middleware' => 'oauth'], function() {
       // routes which needs oauth token verification.
    })

});
```